# Pillow on mac not showing image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a hangman style program that calls on Pillows to display images, but instead it just opens a python process as depicted in the images while displaying nothing:

[image]

[image]

I've installed Pillows successfully, and running the program on a Windows PC with WinPy opens the image.

Comment: Have you imported Pillow into your script, something like `import pillow`?

Comment: @downshift thanks for the response. The helper file does this:
"import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk"

Comment: @downshift how do I change those two lines so this works for me?

Comment: change what two lines? I don't see any lines of code using PIL

Comment: @downshift I have a helper file that does all of the GUI work that I import initially. that helper file imports the following at the start of the file:

import tkinter as tk, import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk, import threading
import queue
import os

Comment: you're using PyCharm IDE on mac, sorry I don't know how that would work on mac with an IDE, I'm only familiar with installing with `pip` and running on command-line

Comment: @downshift thanks you regardless!

Comment: no worries someone may help, good luck